# No Such table error(while the table is already exist)... in sqlite database android

Tags: android, sqlite

Android Monitor:

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
        no such table: dates (code 1): , 
    while compiling: SELECT dateId FROM dates
```

This is my dates table:

```
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+Date_TABLE+"("+
                KEY_DATE_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
                KEY_DATE+" DATE);"
        );
```

Comment: Lose the semicolon at the end of the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: `"CREATE TABLE " + Date_TABLE + " ("
                        
                        + KEY_DATE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
                        + KEY_DATE + " DATE" + ")";`

Comment: The problem is not the semicolon (;), but he missed a space. I always use the semicolon at the end, and it works fine.

Comment: @AngeloParente You are right about the space. But the semicolon is perfectly USELESS.

Comment: @Rotwang Yes, I know :) it is just habit

Comment: A bad practice. You are adding 2 bytes (1 Unicode character) to every SQL command or query. So your app size will grow a (negligible) little.

Comment: This time it gives me this error:04-01 23:44:29.942 3924-3924/com.example.jihad_eng.test E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: studentSubjectId.                              db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+STUDENT_TABLE+" ("+
                    KEY_STUDENT_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , "+
                    KEY_STUDENTS_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                    KEY_STUDENTS_MARK+" INTEGER , "+
                    KEY_STUDENT_DATE_ID+" FOREIGN KEY (" +
                    KEY_STUDENT_SUBJECT_ID+") REFERENCES "+SUBJECTS_TABLE+" ("+
                    KEY_SUBJECTS_ID+"));"
            );

Answer (score 1):

You miss a space after the `Date_TABLE`, should be:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+Date_TABLE+" ("+
            KEY_DATE_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
            KEY_DATE+" DATE);"
    );
```

This way it creates the table properly.

Let me know if it hepls!

Comment: Questions involving simple typo errors should be voted to close, not answered.

Comment: I didn't know that, sorry